# Normal line to cycloid

Tags: calculus, parametric, curves

A Cycloid is given by 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 & x(t) = 3 \cdot (t-\sin t)\\ 
 & y(t) = 3\cdot(1-\cos t)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I need to find the parametrized curve for the Normal line $x(s,t)$, $y(s,t)$  that passes through the point $ (x(t), y(t))$, where $s$ is the parameter for the Normal line.

Answer (score 1):

$$
X(s,t) = x(t) -\dot y(t)\, s
$$
$$
Y(s,t) = y(t) +\dot x(t)\, s
$$

where $x,y$ are those of the cycloid, and $X,Y$ are those of the normal.

**Update:**

The derivatives are:
$$
\dot x(t) = 3-3\cos t
$$
$$
\dot y(t) = +3\sin t
$$

Therefore:
$$
X(s,t) = 3(t-\sin t) -3s\sin t = 3t - 3\sin t (1+s)
$$
$$
Y(s,t) = 3(1-\cos t) +3s(1-\cos t) = 3(1-\cos t)(1+s).
$$